# Symfony / liip_imagine : image path resolution results in 404

Tags: php, symfony, liipimaginebundle

Server configuration

```
Symfony 4.4.2
Apache 2.4.29
PHP: 7.3
Hosting: AWS LightSail
```

I use the liip_imagine bundle to process uploaded images and display them in twig templates using  `asset()`. Unfortunately, the images URL resolves to 404 and I cannot figure out why.

Here is the relevant twig templating :

```html
<div class="col">
  <p>{{ 'Current image' | trans }}</p>
      {% if module.image != '' %}
           <img style="width: 180px;" src="{{ asset(module.image | imagine_filter('learningModuleImage')) }}" alt="">
       {% endif %}
</div>
```

I checked this:

- the files are correctly uploaded in the /public/upload folder.
- module.image does contain the image hashed name and extension: `da305b9a0fee3eb7bdc5bfc9b64e88ff.jpeg`
- The real url:  `/public/upload/da305b9a0fee3eb7bdc5bfc9b64e88ff.jpeg`
- The generated url: `https://domain.tld/media/cache/learningModuleImage/da305b9a0fee3eb7bdc5bfc9b64e88ff.jpeg`
- The configuration:

```
liip_imagine:
    loaders:
        default:
            filesystem:
                data_root:
                    - "%kernel.project_dir%/public/upload"
                    - "%kernel.project_dir%/public/assets/img"

    resolvers:
        default:
            web_path:
                web_root: "%kernel.project_dir%/public/upload"
                cache_prefix: media/cache

    filter_sets:
        cache: ~
        learningModuleImage:
            filters:
                downscale:
                    max: [512, 512]
        profile:
            filters:
                downscale:
                    max: [512, 512]

        # the name of the "filter set"
        thumb:
            # adjust the image quality to 75%
            # quality: 75

            # list of transformations to apply (the "filters")
            filters:
                # create a thumbnail: set size to 120x90 and use the "outbound" mode
                # to crop the image when the size ratio of the input differs
                thumbnail: { size: [128, 128], mode: outbound }
                # create a 2px black border: center the thumbnail on a black background
                # 4px larger to create a 2px border around the final image
                # background: { size: [124, 94], position: center, color: '#000000' }
```

I also checked the Virtual Host :

```sh
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName domain.tld

        DocumentRoot /var/www/project/public
        DirectoryIndex /index.php

        <Directory /var/www/project/public>
                AllowOverride All
                Order Allow,Deny
                Allow from All
                Options -MultiViews
                Require all granted

                FallbackResource /index.php
         </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error-project.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access-project.log combined

        # Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.tld/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.tld/privkey.pem
        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Have you tried passing default resolver name in specific filter set?  Your configuration doesn't specify cache at bundle level so try to define cache: default under liip_imagine config so all other filters inherit that configuration

Comment: @MaulikParmar thank you for the suggestion. I tried your suggestion, still no dice on the image display but now the generated images are stored in the /public/upload//media/cache/{filter}/ folder. As far as I knew, I thought they would be stored in /var/cache/prod/ folder.  Is that normal ?

Comment: @MaulikParmar In fact, if i could simply prepend the generated path with "upload" it would work. Is it possible to do it bundle wide ?

Comment: there may be a typo, ` <img style="width: 180px;" src="{{ asset(module.image | imagine_filter('learningModuleImage')) }}" alt=""> ` should be ` <img style="width: 180px;" src="{{ asset(module.image) | imagine_filter('learningModuleImage') }}" alt=""> ` as imgine filter is applied on top of asset, not as argument.

Comment: ah, good catch!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it!

Here is the working configuration. Thank you @MaulikParmar for your tip!

```
liip_imagine:
    loaders:
        default:
            filesystem:
                data_root:
                    - "%kernel.project_dir%/public/upload"
                    - "%kernel.project_dir%/public/assets/img"

    resolvers:
        default:
            web_path:
                web_root: "%kernel.project_dir%/public"
                cache_prefix: media/cache

    filter_sets:
        cache: ~
        learningModuleImage:
            cache: default
            filters:
                downscale:
                    max: [512, 512]
        profile:
            filters:
                downscale:
                    max: [512, 512]

        # the name of the "filter set"
        thumb:
            # adjust the image quality to 75%
            # quality: 75
            cache: default
            # list of transformations to apply (the "filters")
            filters:
                # create a thumbnail: set size to 120x90 and use the "outbound" mode
                # to crop the image when the size ratio of the input differs
                thumbnail: { size: [128, 128], mode: outbound }
                # create a 2px black border: center the thumbnail on a black background
                # 4px larger to create a 2px border around the final image
                # background: { size: [124, 94], position: center, color: '#000000' }
```